# How to get the target of a UIBarButtonItem

Tags: objective-c, ios

I have the following code in a UIViewController subclass:

```
MyViewController *viewController = [[MyViewController alloc] init];
viewController.title = title;

UIBarButtonItem *doneButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image"]
                                                               style:UIBarButtonItemStyleDone
                                                              target:self 
                                                              action:@selector(mySelector)]; 
viewController.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = doneButton;


 NSLog(@"Class name:%@",[viewController.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem.target className]);
```

The code crashes on the NSLog statement and there is a warning saying no className method found. Isn't the target property an object, and therefore I should be able to call className on it?

What I'm actually trying to do eventually is call mySelector from the viewController without pressing the button. Is there a good way to do this?

Comment: className isn't a method on NSObject.  Is the real question related to the paragraph at the end, or the code in the middle.  To call the selector w/out pressing the button, just call the method directly.

Comment: `className` is not available on iOS. Use `NSStringFromClass([anObject class])` instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To perform the selector directly, try calling performSelector:

```
    [[doneButton target] performSelector:[doneButton action]];
```

Answer (score 3):

The correct method is class instead of className.

If your trying to simulate a touch on the button why not just write:

```
[self mySelector];
```

Comment: Thanks Mathieu, that worked. The reason I can't call [self mySelector] is that I'm calling this from MyViewController, and the only reference I have to the "self" in my code above is through the doneButton. So I need to get the object instance and the selector from the done button.